# is there any experimental method for measurement of thickness at atomic scale?

Tags: atomic-physics, experimental-technique, scales

is there any  experimental method for measurement of thickness at atomic scale?
there are some methods for measurement of thickness even at nano scales such as AFM,TEM but my question is about atomic scale?
notice:
I'd like to know how can we measure the thickness "at atomic Dimensions"?(experimental method)

Comment: If you have a uniform layer, you can use interferometry.  The rainbow-coloured oil stains on water, they are few molecules thick and you can measure this thickness by naked eye looking at the colors

Comment: Light absorption may be another way

Comment: AFM and TEM I guess can go down to 1/10 nanometer, that is about an atom

Comment: AFM was used to measure one-layer graphene

Comment: At the atomic level there are the form factors:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_factor_(quantum_field_theory)  "In general, the Fourier transforms of form factor components correspond to electric charge or magnetic profile space distributions (such as the charge radius) of the hadron involved.".  At the individual scale the thickness depends on the energy of the probe.